# How to get server message?

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

If you try to visit `ftp.yealink.com` you will get a MessageBox saying:

> The Server ftp://ftp.yealink.com:21 requires a username and a password.

How do I receive the above text using C#?

Can it be done through the WebClient class?

Edit: I think some of you misunderstood me. I am not looking to connect to the FTP server, or handle the exception. All I want is a string with the value: "The Server ftp://ftp.yealink.com:21 requires a username and a password."

Comment: have you tried connecting to the ftp server? what have you tried?

Comment: You could look into the `FtpWebRequest` library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When connecting you will receive a `WebException` with `StatusCode` `421`. This means `Not authorized`. Handle the exception and retry.

Given the comments you place I think you are looking for the `WelcomeMessage` and `BannerMessage` from the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `WebClient` class to connect to an ftp site, you need to create a `NetworkCredentials` instance to store your login info (username, password):

```
var client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password") };

try
{
  var data = client.DownloadData(<some uri to a file path on the ftp site>);
  ...
}
catch (WebException e)
{
  // handle any exceptions
}
```

More info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

EDIT:

You clarified that you're looking for the popup text shown in your browser when clicking on the ftp link.  The text string of "The Server ... requires a username and a password" is generated by your browser (Chrome). Firefox pops up a message box stating "Enter username and password for ..." and Safari says "Enter your name and password for the server ..." The text you're trying to capture isn't output by the ftp server.

Comment: True, but sometimes this message box has other messages. I've seen a FTP say "Please be aware that the server is shutting down in a couple of days ... Enter Username and password". How do I get this message?

Comment: The `FtpWebResponse` class has a `BannerMessage` property which is the message sent by the server to the client prior to authenticating - that might be what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.bannermessage(v=vs.110).aspx